# mac homebrew git command not found

Tags: macos, sh, homebrew

When I run the following on a mac from the command line it works fine:

```
git submodule foreach "git checkout develop; git pull"
```

... but when I run it from within a .sh script it gives a *git: command not found* error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.14.2/libexec/git-core/git-submodule: line 355: “git: command not found
```

The full script is as follows. The *checkout* and *pull* work, but *submodule foreach* throws the error:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
git checkout develop && git pull
git submodule foreach “git checkout develop; git pull”
exit 0
```

Advice I've found says to make sure usr/bin is in my path. But here's what I see when I do echo $PATH (seems to already be there):

```
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
```

Comment: Please share your script.

Comment: added script above

Comment: Your quotes are off. It should be `"git checkout develop; git pull"` instead of `“git checkout develop; git pull”`.

Comment: Interesting. i just noticed that while testing again. And I notice that TextEdit automatically changes those quotes. I see them change milliseconds after I type them in. Guess I need to use a different editor?

Comment: Thanks, bfontaine! This solved the problem (I re-typed the quotes in another editor other than TextEdit). Feel free to add your comment as an answer if interested and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: You probably have *"Rich Text Format"* selected in **TextEdit**. Just go to `Format->Make Plain Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are off.

It should be `"git checkout develop; git pull"` instead of `“git checkout develop; git pull”`.